# Dynamic UICollectionView inside dynamic UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview, dynamic, uicollectionview

I have a **collection view** that is **dynamic** and can have any number of cells in it. It is positioned inside a **table view cell**.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

My **table view** is correctly configured to be **dynamic** because the other cells work fine so the issue is not there.

Here is what I currently have... As you can see there is no **collection view below**

[image]

This is what my desired out come is... **(Forcing a height constraint on the collection view)**

[image]

I have configured constraints on all sides of the **collection view** correctly, as it works when I give a **fix height constraint**. But this defeats the object of a **dynamic collection view...**

I have linked an outlet to the **UICollectionViewFlowLayout** and set an **estimated cell size** and given the cell the **correct constraints** on the **label** inside as you can see in the image where I **forced the height constraint.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a subclass for collectionView and override intrinsicContentSize.

```
class DynamicCollectionView: UICollectionView {
  override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    if !__CGSizeEqualToSize(bounds.size, self.intrinsicContentSize) {
        self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
     }
  }

   override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    return collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize
   }
}
```

2. In Interface builder change the class of your collectionView to DynamicCollectionView (subclass UICollectionView).
3. Set estimated cell size of UICollectionViewFlowLayout.

   ```
       flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 1,height: 1)
   ```

Comment: This is only partially working for me.  When the tableView first loads, the cell (containing the DynamicCollectionView) does not dynamically adjust its height.  It is only after scrolling the tableView and coming back to the cell, that it correctly adjusts its height.